# Azure Automation Error 'DynamicActivity': Expected an input parameter value of type

Tags: powershell, azure

When using the Microsoft Sample-Using-RunbookParameter script and running the following Azure Automation PowerShell:

```
$date = Get-Date
$Params = @{"Name"="World";"Number"=1; "Date"=$date; "SayGoodBye"=$TRUE; "StringArray"="[1,'astringvalue',2]"}
Start-AzureAutomationRunbook -AutomationAccountName CMTEST -Name Sample-Using-RunbookParameters -Parameters $Params
```

I get the following exception:

```
The values provided for the root activity's arguments did not satisfy the root activity's requirements:
'DynamicActivity': Expected an input parameter value of type 'System.Boolean' for parameter named 'SayGoodbye'.
'DynamicActivity': Expected an input parameter value of type 'System.DateTime' for parameter named 'Date'.
 jParameter name: rootArgumentValues
```

If I look in the Azure Automation Job log I see the following input parameters:

```
DATE Fri, 08 Aug 2014 15:26:14 GMT
NAME World
NUMBER 1
SAYGOODBYE True
STRINGARRAY [1,'astringvalue',2]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a bug in the Azure Automation cmdlets that will be fixed in an upcoming Azure PowerShell release (if not the next one, the one after that). Basically, the cmdlet is supposed to serialize each job parameter as json, but is currently passing them as each as a string.

Also, once this is fixed, instead doing the above in your code as you are currently doing:

```
"StringArray"="[1,'astringvalue',2]"
```

You will want to use a proper PowerShell array:

```
$SomeArray = @(1, "astringvalue", 2)
"StringArray"=$SomeArray
```

Comment: I get this error when a parameter for a runbook is specified as a string, but then is executed using a numeric value, when Started via the UI directly (either published, or in the test window) & when using the ISE Add-On for AA: it complains the numeric value mismatches the expected string type.

Comment: I suggest starting your own SO question. But if you are passing a number as an int, set the parameter type to [int]. If you are passing a number as a string, set the parameter type to [string].

Comment: Right now it's not an issue during actual execution via webhook or as child runbooks (don't know about as new job), just when using ISE or the Portal UI to start the runbook. IIRC simply wrapping the numbers in quotes mitigated the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass BOOLEAN value using `$` signature. like below:

```
$params = @{“AZURERESOURCEGROUP”=”Infra-ResourceGroup”;”SHUTDOWN”=$TRUE}
```

In above example `resourcegroup` name will be passed as string into `AZURERESOURCEGROUP` parameter. To pass `BOOLEAN` value you can use `$TRUE`/`$FALSE`.