# Starting Runbook via Azure API, Portal, or ISE Add-On yields "input parameter type mismatch" error

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-automation

Given a simple runbook:

```
workflow test
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param([string] $NumericString)

    write-output $NumericString
}
```

When starting it with a numeric value (ie: 5) via the Azure Portal as a new Job (published), via the Test Pane, or using the Azure Automation PowerShell ISE Add-On, the following error is returned and the execution Fails.

[edit] Just out of curiosity I tried some other values. 'true' or 'false' (without quotes in ise/the ui) will also cause the error (and are sent to the API inside quotes).[\edit]

> The values provided for the root activity's arguments did not satisfy
>   the root activity's requirements: 'DynamicActivity': Expected an input
>   parameter value of type 'System.String' for parameter named 'Numeric'.
>   Parameter name: rootArgumentValues

AFAIK, this is not a factor when I've executed via a parent runbook, webhook, etc.

The PowerShell ISE Add-On issues this PUT request to the API:
(`https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<id>/resourceGroups/<rg>/providers/Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/<aa>/runbooks/<rb>/draft/testJob?api-version=2015-10-31`)

```
{
    "parameters": {
        "Numeric": "5"  <-- notice it's a string
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This would appear to be a bug, similar to [Azure Automation Error 'DynamicActivity': Expected an input parameter value of type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25207151/)

To mitigate the issue, just wrap your numeric value in quotes in the Portal or ISE Add-On

If you are starting runbooks outside of the formal SDKs, it appears you need to know about required extra escaping for sending Numeric or Boolean values for string parameters (in the least).

This is what the subsequent PUT request should look like (from ISE Add-On)

```
{
    "parameters": {
        "Numeric": "\"5\""  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the Automation portal and ISE add on. For portal, this should be fixed in a week or so. For ISE add on, can you please file a bug on this here: https://github.com/azureautomation/azure-automation-ise-addon/issues

Comment: After coming back to this, this seems to be a bug in how the API parses the incoming JSON. The JSON that ISE sends is valid string data. Per http://www.json.org & ECMA-404, a number in JSON looks like `{ "prop": 5  }` (no quotes) whereas a string has quotes. Should any REST consumer have to implement one-off JSON serialization/notation to appease the API? (Or is the API fixed, but the Portal and ISE still use the old version?)

Comment: I just tested this. The API supports int and strings to be passed as their true types (ex 5 and "five", respectively), but for all other types (booleans, arrays, complex objects) you must currently pass the value as a JSON string (ex "true", "[\"a\",\"b\"]", "{\"asdf\":123}" ). If you pass an int as a string (ex "5"), it will be interpreted by the service as a string. Above the API layer, the Automation portal and ISE add on were in some cases passing values incorrectly vs what is required. That has now been fixed in the portal, but not in the ISE add on yet.